# Меню аккордеон, как закрыть активный пункт меню?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Есть меню типо аккордеона, нужно сделать что бы открытый пункт можно было закрыть, то есть что бы 2 элемента были закрыты.

P.S. Джиес только начал изучать сильно не ругайте :)

```js
var toggleMenu = document.getElementsByClassName("main-footer__btn"),
    menuList = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-list");

for (var i = 0; i < toggleMenu.length; i++) {
  toggleMenu[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (!(this.classList.contains("main-footer__btn--active")))
      for (var i = 0; i < toggleMenu.length; i++) {
        toggleMenu[i].classList.remove("main-footer__btn--active");
      }
      this.classList.add("main-footer__btn--active");
  })
}
```

```css
.menu-list {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
  }

  .main-footer__btn.main-footer__btn--active + .menu-list,
  .main-footer__btn.main-footer__btn--active + .main-footer__address-wrapper > .menu-list {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 26px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="main-footer__menu-box">
  <h3>Разделы сайта</h3>
  <button class="main-footer__btn">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Открыть меню</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">О компании</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">Продукты</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">Производство печатных плат</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">Монтаж печатных плат</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">Комплектующие</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">Доставка</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">Контакты</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="main-footer__address-box">
  <h3>Наш офис</h3>
  <button class="main-footer__btn main-footer__btn--active">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Открыть меню</span>
  </button>
  <address class="main-footer__address-wrapper">
    <ul class="menu-list">
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <p>г. Мытищи, Олимпийский проспект, д.10</p>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <p>
          <a href="tel:+74955894050">+7 (495) 589-40-50</a>
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <p>
          <a href="tel:+79250038767">+7 (925) 003-87-67</a>
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <p>
          <a href="tel:+792692608079">+7 (926) 926-080-79</a>
        </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </address>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно подробней? Что-то не совсем понимаю что происходит здесь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавила `else { this.classList.remove("main-footer__btn--active"); }` :

```js
var toggleMenu = document.getElementsByClassName("main-footer__btn"),
    menuList = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-list");

for (var i = 0; i < toggleMenu.length; i++) {
  toggleMenu[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (!(this.classList.contains("main-footer__btn--active"))) {
      for (var i = 0; i < toggleMenu.length; i++) {
        toggleMenu[i].classList.remove("main-footer__btn--active");
      }
      this.classList.add("main-footer__btn--active");
    } else {
      this.classList.remove("main-footer__btn--active");
    }
      
  });
}
```

```css
.menu-list {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
  }

  .main-footer__btn.main-footer__btn--active + .menu-list,
  .main-footer__btn.main-footer__btn--active + .main-footer__address-wrapper .menu-list {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 26px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="main-footer__menu-box">
  <h3>Разделы сайта</h3>
  <button class="main-footer__btn">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Открыть меню</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">О компании</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">Продукты</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">Производство печатных плат</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">Монтаж печатных плат</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">Комплектующие</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">Доставка</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">Контакты</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="main-footer__address-box">
  <h3>Наш офис</h3>
  <button class="main-footer__btn main-footer__btn--active">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Открыть меню</span>
  </button>
  <address class="main-footer__address-wrapper">
    <ul class="menu-list">
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <p>г. Мытищи, Олимпийский проспект, д.10</p>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <p>
          <a href="tel:+74955894050">+7 (495) 589-40-50</a>
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <p>
          <a href="tel:+79250038767">+7 (925) 003-87-67</a>
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <p>
          <a href="tel:+792692608079">+7 (926) 926-080-79</a>
        </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </address>
</div>
```

Если я правильно понимаю вопрос.

Comment: Да всё правильно и блин всё настолько просто! Вот я дятел...
Спасибо огромное!!